# What is Unity going to do about Application menus?

Tags: unity, 11.10

Gnome Shell makes use of a single application menu that is always present in the top bar. It gets its contents via GtkApplication. In the current stable version nothing really uses it, but for GNOME 3.2 that will probably be changing. For example, a mockup for GNOME Contacts has an application menu that is mandatory to use the application to its fullest:
http://afaikblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/presenting-gnome-contacts/

Are there any plans for how Unity will accommodate this?

Comment: I'm closing this because

Comment: This question's a bit too open ended and most answers will just be speculation. (This is probably more appropriate on the ayatana mailing list)

Comment: Sorry yes, that's pretty much what I wanted to say but never managed to... just as I didn't quite manage to close it either. I'm clearly off my game. Future releases are moving targets and when design changes can land on the final day of beta (they have before), there's no guarantee an answer here will be true when it comes to the released product.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I'll head over there then :)